# Google fonts not loading in PDF File - using puppeteer npm

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I saw couple of posts but doesn't work for me. So reposting.

Basically my requirement is to send a confirmation email and same email template to be converted to pdf file and sent as attachment. Everything seems to be working fine only issue is I don't see font changes in pdf file.

Below is the css imports for google fonts in **main.handlebars** file

```
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

Below is my code that converts html to pdf.

```
exports.convertHtmlToPdfBuffer = async (htmlContent) => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ args: ["--no-sandbox"] });
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    // await page.screenshot({ path: "beforeTimeout.png" });
    // await page.waitForTimeout(15000);
    // await page.screenshot({ path: "afterTimeOut.png" });
    // await page.evaluateHandle("document.fonts.ready");
    await page.setContent(htmlContent, { waitUntil: "networkidle2" });

    const pdfBuffer = await page.pdf({
        format: "a4",
        margin: {
            top: "50px",
            right: "0px",
            bottom: "50px",
            left: "0px",
        },
    });

    await page.close();
    await browser.close();

    return pdfBuffer;
};
```

Comment: have you found solution for this ?

Comment: @ApurvChaudhary no I didn't find any...

Comment: **await page.setContent(htmlContent, { waitUntil: "networkidle2" });** this is working fine for me.